# -webkit-border-radius acts differently from -moz-border-radius

Tags: safari, css

My website is showing up differently on Safari vs Firefox.  I would like to have the CSS make it look the same on Safari.  I know that I could use two div boxes, one for the outline, one for the image, but I like how on Firefox I only need one and it curves the outline and the image.  Is there anyway to have Safari curve the outline and the image?

Safari:

[image: Safari border radius]

Firefox:

[image: Firefox border raidus]

`<img src="asset.jpg"  class="example">`

`img.example {
width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  padding: 18px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}`

Comment: I have provided an example with it wrapped in a div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in webkit browsers

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/TdXGS/)

So in short, yes, for now you have to wrap the image in a div. Sucks.

See these bug reports:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82417
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30475

For now, wrap it in a div, [as I have done here](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/TdXGS/2/)

Comment: Looks like this is a bug that has been there since 2009, anyway to get it fixed? Any idea on when it will get fixed?

Comment: Hopefully soon, but you'll still have to support old builds, because not everyone will update. Welcome to f***ing web design!

Comment: Looks like this issue persists. I see this in http://shapebootstrap.net/demo/html/corlate/contact-us.html

How do I solve this? In other browsers its a perfect circle, whereas in safari it's square.