# Border radius doesn't work on safari?

Tags: css

I am creating a WordPress theme, and I have four images, that should be displayed as circles with border.

My HMTL code is the following:

```
<div class="row homeCategoryImageLinks">
    <div class="columns large-3">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/195x195" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="columns large-3">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/195x195" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="columns large-3">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/195x195" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="columns large-3">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/195x195" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS code:

```
.homeCategoryImageLinks a
{
    z-index: 3502;
    display: block;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.homeCategoryImageLinks a img
{
    display: block;
    border: 5px solid #FFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
}
```

The problem is that, while this code work fine in any browser I have test, doesn't work in Safari.

The desired result should be the following:

[image]

and Safari return this:

[image]

How can I fix that issue ?

**Note** : The above code work in every tested browser as desired, but not for Safari. The Safari web browser is the exception.

**Note 2** : Here you can see live the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/87EZV/1/

Kind regards.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/87EZV/2/, display `inline-block` with `margin` instead of `border-width` does the trick. However, I don't know the reason of this behaviour.

Comment: You will get answer here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094778/webkit-border-radius-acts-differently-from-moz-border-radius

you have to use different approach as suggested by fellows

Comment: @wikijames your comment was very helpfull ! If you like posted as an answer to upvote you. Thanks ...

Comment: @MerianosNikos Your welcome :). i posted it as an answer.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Are Safari & Mobile Safari rendering rounded borders with radius and padding incorrectly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444806/are-safari-mobile-safari-rendering-rounded-borders-with-radius-and-padding-inc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You will get answer [CLICK HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094778/webkit-border-radius-acts-differently-from-moz-border-radius). 
>   You have to use different approach as suggested by fellows.
>
> You have to use this or any different approach till safari fix this bug.

```
.class{
        display: inline-block;
        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;

}
.class img{

        border: 10px solid #ffffff;
        width:100px;/*as like if needed*/  
        height:100px;/*as like if needed*/  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Safari is buggy with `border-radius`: [-webkit-border-radius acts differently from -moz-border-radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094778/webkit-border-radius-acts-differently-from-moz-border-radius)

I recommend applying `border-radius` and `overflow: hidden` to a parent wrapper for the image. That parent will clip the image inside it.

You may need to apply `display: block` or `position: relative` to ensure the browser accepts the styling.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.homeCategoryImageLinks a{
        display: inline-block;
        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
        -moz-border-radius: 50%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
        border: 5px solid #fff;
}
```

Heres ur **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/87EZV/5/)**